# How to connect 16x2 lcd to esp8266?

Tags: lcd, multiplexer, encoder, decoder, esp8266

I have ESP8266-01 this model

[image]

I Updated the frimware to nodeMCU and uploaded the web server code and tested by blinking led via web browser. Now I want to test that if I can send text data from web browser to ESP8266 and show that text on LCD screen similer to thi one

[image]

I know how to operate this LCD and display text on this LCD but my problem is that in this ESP8266 there are only to GPIO pin GPIO0 is for uploading frimware and GPIO2 is that free for send signal to outer device. I have not much knowladge about electronics so is there any way to achive this with minimum extra components if required.

**Update:-**

I found some link where they are showing its working but I am not able to figure it out how.

here are the links

1. [ESP8266 WITH 16X2 I2C LCD](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=841#p11075)
2. [Image](http://digiland.tw/viewtopic.php?pid=14095#p14095)

Comment: Use a module with more exposed pins.

Comment: but why when I can achive this with same module ?

Comment: You don't have enough pins; you will need external parts.

Comment: Yes I am asking about what parts I'll required

Answer (score 2):

With only a single gpio, you either need a one-wire port expander, or use the serial port to a serial backpack for a lcd. The two projects you link to use  PCF8574 i2c port expanders. These need two pins, one for data and another for clock.

An expander is a IC that takes one protocol like i2c, spi, or otherwise, and provides a number of gpio. Like a middle man when you don't have enough pins free.

The PCF8574 for example is one of the first i2c port expanders providing a simple 8 bit interface, perfect for a lcd in 4 bit mode.

If you really only have one pin available, if the firmware can do the timing required for One-Wire, that may be an option. Otherwise you will need an esp board with more gpio available.

Comment: Thanks I realy expecting someting like this can you please explain more about expender and where to buy ?

Comment: An expander is a IC that takes one protocol like i2c, spi, or otherwise, and provides a number of gpio. Like a middle man when you don't have enough pins free.

Comment: The PCF8574 for example is one of the first i2c port expanders providing a simple 8 bit interface, perfect for a lcd in 4 bit mode

Answer (score -1):

It is actually possible all four pins, take a look at this:

http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ESP8266/GPIOpins/ESP8266_01_pin_magic.html

and this:

https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2016/10/11/using-the-4-pins-of-the-esp8266-01/

Comment: Why the downvote? And what is the problem in using a cheap i2c adapter to drive the LCD?